# differentiate $\frac {dx}{dt}$ when $x=(1+e^{-2u})^{-0.5}$

Tags: derivatives

I am stuck in what would be simple differentiation:

When $\dot x =\frac {dx}{dt}$  now when $x=(1+e^{-2u})^{-0.5}$
I think I can write:
$$\dot x =\frac {d(1+e^{-2u})^{-0.5} }{dt}$$

But can I proceed with:

$$\dot x =- \frac{1}{2}(-2) (1+e^{-2 \dot u})^{-1.5}  $$

Comment: $x$ is not a function of $t$, at least not explicitly.  Did you mean $\frac {dx}{du}
$?

Comment: If you are assuming that $u=u(t)$ then note that $\frac d{dt} e^{u(t)}=\frac {du}{dt}\times e^{u(t)}$.

Comment: I wish to find an expression for $\ dot u$

Comment: @JoeGoldiamond: what don't you ask that then ?

Comment: I tried to ask that: for example: when $x=u+1$, then $\dot x = \dot u$.

Comment: Please don't be quite so quick to accept an answer, when many people may not even have seen the question yet! I put a fair bit of effort into answering it, but my Internet connection went down for a few minutes, and by the time it had come back up again, another answer had already been accepted. (Sorry to sound peeved - I'm annoyed with BT as well!) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u$ is a function of $t$, by the chain rule

$$\dot x=-0.5(1+e^{-2u})^{-1.5}\ (-2)e^{-2u}\ \dot u.$$

Comment: I think you lost a minus sign: But I do understand what you are aiming. $$\dot x=-0.5(1+e^{-2u})^{-1.5}\ -2e^{2u}\ \dot u.$$, which can be rewritten: $$\dot x=(1+e^{-2u})^{-1.5}\ e^{2u}\ \dot u.$$

Comment: @JoeGoldiamond: I have fixed the sign. You lost it as well in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you meant $e^{-2t}$, you'll need implicit differentiation.

Here, we use the chain rule, which states that:

$$x=[f(u)]^n \to \frac {dx}{dt} =n\cdot f'(u)\frac {du}{dt}[f(u)]^{n-1} $$

Comment: No didn't meant: $e^{-2t}$, what I try to do is a substitution. To get from $x$ to $u$

Answer (score 1):

If $f(y) = \left(1+e^{-2y}\right)^{-0.5}$ (where $y$ is any real number), then you have
$$
x(t) = f(u(t)),
$$
so by the Chain Rule,
$$
x'(t) = f'(u(t))u'(t),
$$
i.e.,
$$
\dot{x} = f'(u)\dot{u}.
$$
But the dot notation led you astray. You wrote, in effect,
$$
x'(t) = f'(u'(t)) \ \ \text{[Wrong.]}
$$
That's not all, though: you also went wrong in differentiating $f$ itself. Making the use of the Chain Rule more explicit, for a second time, let $z$ be any strictly positive real number, and let $g(z) = (1+z)^{-0.5}$, so that
$$
f(y) = g\!\left(e^{-2y}\right).
$$
Then
$$
f'(y) = g'\!\left(e^{-2y}\right)\left(-2e^{-2y}\right),
$$
and, although you differentiated $g$ correctly, you lost a factor of $e^{-2y} = e^{-2u(t)}$ along the way.

Comment: Absolute clear. I now know where I went wrong.

Comment: Thanks - I'm mollified now! (Even though my wretched Internet connection went down a second time.) :)